# I'm not able to click a link using querySelector

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to download a file from a website by selecting a particular date. Inspect element showing href content, but not able to click on it.

WEBPAGE CODE

```
<td>
<a href="/content/historical/EQUITIES/2021/FEB/cm02FEB2021bhav.csv.zip" target="new">cm02FEB2021bhav.csv.zip</a><br>
</td>
```

MY VBA CODE

```
Dim files As String

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend


Do

Set el = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set el = IE.document.getelementbyid("h_filetype")
On Error GoTo 0
DoEvents
Loop While el Is Nothing
IE.document.getelementbyid("h_filetype").Value = "eqbhav"

Do

Set el = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set el = IE.document.getelementbyid("date")
On Error GoTo 0
DoEvents
Loop While el Is Nothing
IE.document.getelementbyid("date").Value = "02-02-2021

IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "validateInput();", "javascript"

IE.document.querySelector("a[href^='/content/historical/EQUITIES/']").Click
```

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
IE.document.querySelector("a[href^='/content/historical/EQUITIES/']").Click
```

Comment: Also, rather than just stating "not working" can you add more detail please? Are there any error messages? If so, what and where?

Answer (score 2):

Your QuerySelector `.querySelector("a[href^='/content/historical/EQUITIES/']")` can't work, because `/content/historical/EQUITIES/` is only part of the url. Another reason is, after the execution of the JS you must give the document a chance to generate the wanted url.

I have completed your code up to the `Click`. Then you have to let some time pass again so that the bar with the save button is displayed at the bottom of IE. Then you have to work with `SendKeys()` to trigger the save. The file will then end up in the default download folder of IE. If no extra folder has been set up, this is the system folder *Downloads*.

```
Sub TestClick()

Dim files As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim el As Object

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.navigate "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm"
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
  
  Do
    Set el = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set el = IE.document.getelementbyid("h_filetype")
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
  Loop While el Is Nothing
  IE.document.getelementbyid("h_filetype").Value = "eqbhav"
  Do
    Set el = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set el = IE.document.getelementbyid("date")
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
  Loop While el Is Nothing
  IE.document.getelementbyid("date").Value = "02-02-2021"
  IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "validateInput();", "javascript"
  
  'You must spend time to generate the link you want
  Do
    Set el = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set el = IE.document.getelementbyid("spanDisplayBox").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents
  Loop While el Is Nothing
  'Than you can click it
  el.Click
  
  'Here more of your code
  '...
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't have time to check the html earlier today but looking again I see the OP should have used contains * operator rather than starts with ^ operator i.e. `ie.Navigate IE.document.querySelector("a[href*='/content/historical/EQUITIES/']").href`

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for the explanation. I was not aware of the operators. That's why I solved it with the get methods.

Comment: That's cool. I only commented in case you wanted to expand on your answer where you already note the current attempt fails due to partial string. Just that they expect href start to be `\.....` because they used ^ operator.